# Add more than one parameter in Twig path

Tags: symfony, twig

How to add more than one parameter in Twig path?
Say you have this route :

```
article_show:
    pattern:  /article/{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeArticleBundle:Article:show }
```

You can do this in your twig template :

```
{{ path('article_show', { 'slug': article.slug }) }}
```

but what if you have this in your routing file:

```
_files_manage:
    pattern: /files/management/project={idproject}&user={iduser}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTestBundle:File:manage }
```

It looks like they didn't cover this in their documentation.

Comment: Did you miss guess ("?") before project ?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

You can pass as many arguments as you want, separating them by commas:

```
{{ path('_files_manage', {project: project.id, user: user.id}) }}
```

Answer (score 9):

Consider making your route:

```
_files_manage:
    pattern: /files/management/{project}/{user}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTestBundle:File:manage }
```

since they are required fields.   It will make your url's prettier, and be a bit easier to manage.

Your Controller would then look like

```
 public function projectAction($project, $user)
```