# How to have twig path() with silex slug?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

In silex I have something like

```
$controllers->get('/{id}', 'Controllers\\Login::index')->bind('login');
```

when in twig I try to get `path('login')` I get exception

```
("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route "login"."). ?
```

I know this is because of {id} and I have to pass a second parameter to `path()` but how should it look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add more than one parameter in Twig path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382093/add-more-than-one-parameter-in-twig-path) this link explain how to pass parameters to path  method in twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass parameters to twig path, use the following syntax:

```
{{ path('login', {'id': 'your-id-here'}) }}
```

you can have a look at the documentation here:

[Path() function documentation, symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path)

You can pass several parameters as explained here:

[SO: several paremeters in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382093/add-more-than-one-parameter-in-twig-path)

Comment: Is it possible to fetch id dynamically instead of hardcode it? I tried {{ app.request.attribute }} but it seems invalid?

Comment: yes just pass value to your template and use it in the path function